# How to handle expired tokens when logging out using Vue.js and JWT?

Tags: java, typescript, spring, vue.js, jwt

I'm developing the front end using Vue.js, and processing authentication using JWT tokens. The current logout processing logic is as follows.

1. The client sends a logout request.
2. The server uses the access token to identify the user, and invalidates all tokens(AT and RT) of the user stored in the DB.

In this process, if the client has an expired token, the server will experience an error when trying to extract the username from the expired token. I thought of two ways to deal with this.

1. It checks whether the token has expired, and if it has expired, logout processing is performed immediately without extracting the user name.
2. Process the expiration of tokens within the extractUsername function. Even if the token expires, the payload is still valid, so it ignores the expiration of the token and extracts the user name from the payload.

The first method is a good security method, but there is a problem that a user with expired tokens cannot handle logouts when they request them to log out. The second method can handle logouts, but using expired tokens can be a bad security method.

I'd like to hear what you think of this problem, or if there's any other good solution. Thank you.

LogoutService

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class LogoutService implements LogoutHandler {

    private final JwtService jwtService;
    private final TokenRepository tokenRepository;

    @Override
    public void logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) {
        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        final String accessToken;
        if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return;
        }
        accessToken = authHeader.substring(7);
        if (StringUtils.hasText(accessToken)) {
            final String username = jwtService.extractUsername(accessToken);
            revokeAllTokensByUsername(username);
        }
    }

    private void revokeAllTokensByUsername(String username) {
        List<Tokens> validTokens = tokenRepository.findAllValidTokenByUsername(username);
        if (!validTokens.isEmpty()) {
            validTokens.forEach(t -> {
                t.setExpired(true);
                t.setRevoked(true);
                tokenRepository.save(t);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

JwtService

```java
private Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser()
                .verifyWith(getSignInKey()).build()
                .parseSignedClaims(token)
                .getPayload();
    }
    
    public String extractUsername(String token) {
        return extrectClaim(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }

    private Date extractExpiration(String token) {
        return extrectClaim(token, Claims::getExpiration);
    }

    public <T> T extrectClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimResolver) {
        final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
        return claimResolver.apply(claims);
    }
```

AuthStore.ts

```js
  async function logout() {
    await instance.post("/auth/logout");
    token.value = "";
    user.value = "";
    await router.push("/auth/login");
  }

  return {
    user,
    token,
    returnURL,
    getUser,
    getToken,
    login,
    refresh,
    logout,
  };
```

Axios-interceptors.ts

```js
instance.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
    const auth = useAuthStore();
    config.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
    config.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${auth.getToken}`;
    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

view.vue

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
async function logout() {
  authStore.logout();
}
</script>

...
<v-sheet class="ma-3">
        <v-btn size="small" @click="logout">logout</v-btn>
</v-sheet>
...
```

Comment: I'm confused: you're sending accesstokens for every REST call, so you keep your accesstoken in the browser obviously. Don't you keep your refresh token in the browser too? Why do you need a tokenRepository in the server? Is your server not completely stateless?

Comment: @GeertPt Now I see. The approach to access token (i.e. axiso interceptor) seems to be wrong. Whenever the router changes, it is issued an access token using the refresh token, but the interpreter seems to have tried to access the access token without changing the router. So where should I set the refresh step? I don't think I can refresh it anymore on the router. If you import the authStore from the p.s interceptor and refresh it, it takes infinite loading.